# reaction between Green tea and sodium bicarbonate

Tags: physical-chemistry

There is a tea in northern Pakistan called noon chai or Kashmiri chai. It is distinct between it is a pink colour. 
The method involves brewing green tea leaves in cold water and adding sodium bicarbonate.

What is the chemistry here?  How does this reaction work and why does the green tea become pink when sodium bicarbonate is added?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/tea/comments/tzexm/baking_soda_to_tea_water/&ved=0ahUKEwjwjN7h5LfUAhVLs48KHZFpDQwQFghbMA0&usg=AFQjCNHeRGLsykGeNr6ag2fr5QCQzIB6OA&sig2=F_X1IF51tfRojOdbj_oAIQ