# Formation of caffeidine in Noon Chai

Tags: organic-chemistry, food-chemistry

Noon Chai (as described in [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76106/reaction-between-green-tea-and-sodium-bicarbonate)) from Kashmir is prepared by adding common salt and sodium bicarbonate to green tea and cooking it for quite some time (~ 30 minutes).

Noon Chai is also associated with gastric cancer; the mechanism is assumed to be endogenous nitrosation of caffeidine by which then carcinogenic nitrosamines ([dinitrosocaffeidine](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Dinitrosocaffeidine#section=Top)) are produced.

The question is: how does Noon Chai get its high amount of caffeidine in the first place?

Somehow the caffeine

[image: caffeine]

is converted to caffeidine

[image: caffeidine]

by the special way to prepare the tea.

What is the reaction that happens there?

Comment: Basic hydrolysis - the sodium bicarbonate generates a basic solution aqueous solution which is then heated.